# How to print months in French with BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, datetime

How can I print months in French with BibTeX?

```
@Misc{url-site,
  key =      {site},
  title =    {\textit{site}},
  month = jun,
  year = {2012},
  howpublished = {URL: \texttt{http://www. a web site.com/}}

}
```

It displays *June*, but I'd like *Juin*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't indicate which bibliography style file you use, so I'll assume that it's the "default" file, viz., `plain.bst`. If so, the problem you're facing is that this file contains the instruction

```
MACRO {jun} {"June"}
```

Thus, the string "jun" in your bib file will be typeset as "June" unless there's an explicit override. You can provide this override by inserting the instruction

```
@string{ jun = "Juin" }
```

at the top of your bib file.

Separately, I'd also recommend that you change the line

```
howpublished = {URL: \texttt{http://www.awebsite.com/}}
```

to

```
howpublished = {URL: \url{http://www.awebsite.com/}}
```

and load the `url` package (which provides the command `\url`). The advantage of taking this approach is that the `url` package can (almost) always choose a suitable line break for long and complicated url strings, letting you avoid massively underfull or overfull lines.

Taking these observations together, your `.bib` file (called, say, urlcite.bib) should contain:

```
@string{ jun = "Juin" }
@Misc{url-site,
  key          = {site},
  title        = {\textit{site}},
  month        = jun,
  year         = 2012,
  howpublished = {URL: \url{http://www.awebsite.com/}}
}
```

A full MWE might then look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}          % for the \url command
\bibliographystyle{plain} % or whatever style file you prefer
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document} 
\cite{url-site} 
\bibliography{urlcite}    % if bib entries are in the file "urlcite.bib"
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

You only have to add one of the following sections to your `.bib` file:

### English

```
@STRING{ jan = "January" }
@STRING{ feb = "February" }
@STRING{ mar = "March" }
@STRING{ apr = "April" }
@STRING{ may = "May" }
@STRING{ jun = "June" }
@STRING{ jul = "July" }
@STRING{ aug = "August" }
@STRING{ sep = "September" }
@STRING{ oct = "October" }
@STRING{ nov = "November" }
@STRING{ dec = "December" }
```

### French

```
@STRING{ jan = "Janvier" }
@STRING{ feb = "F{\'e}vrier" }
@STRING{ mar = "Mars" }
@STRING{ apr = "Avril" }
@STRING{ may = "Mai" }
@STRING{ jun = "Juin" }
@STRING{ jul = "Juilliet" }
@STRING{ aug = "Ao{\^u}t" }
@STRING{ sep = "Septembre" }
@STRING{ oct = "Octobre" }
@STRING{ nov = "Novembre" }
@STRING{ dec = "D{\'e}cembre" }
```

### German

```
@STRING{ jan = "Januar" }
@STRING{ feb = "Februar" }
@STRING{ mar = "M{\"a}rz" }
@STRING{ apr = "April" }
@STRING{ may = "Mai" }
@STRING{ jun = "Juni" }
@STRING{ jul = "Juli" }
@STRING{ aug = "August" }
@STRING{ sep = "September" }
@STRING{ oct = "Oktober" }
@STRING{ nov = "November" }
@STRING{ dec = "Dezember" }
```

Comment: the same problem persist ;(

Comment: @string{Jan = "Janvier"} not STRING{ jan = "Janvier" } Thank you so much for help

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Sorry, I forgot the `@`

Comment: @egreg May I add the German one to your answer for convenience? (so that Germans finding this answer can copy-paste it)